# How do I implement a React Material-UI Component in an Angular2 app?

Tags: angular, reactjs, material-ui, angular2-components

There is very little to no documentation of this out there. In fact, I am starting to doubt ng2 and React can play together. But I'm no expert, so I need your help.

According to Material UI docs for the AppBar [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) This is the code to add it to your component

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

/**
 * A simple example of `AppBar` with an icon on the right.
 * By default, the left icon is a navigation-menu.
 */
const AppBarExampleIcon = () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Title"
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
  />
);

export default AppBarExampleIcon;
```

Problem is, this is documentation for a React Component, not an Angular2 Component.

This is as far as I got in my Angular2 component with the little information that is out there:

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { React } from 'react';
  import { AppBar } from 'material-ui';


  @Component({
      selector: 'app-toolbar',
      templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css']
  })
  export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
      AppBarExampleIcon = `
          <AppBar title="Title" iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" />
      `;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This results in nothing.

Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 1):

React and Angular cannot be mixed like that. Although both use the component syntax what is under the hood is completely different. `Material-UI` is a `Material Design` implementation specifically for `React`.

Try `Angular Material` instead, a `Material Design` implementation for Angular2. It's not as fully fleshed out like `Material-UI` (due to ng2 being newer) but there are still some components you should be able to use with a bit of modification - https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar

Comment: I think I agree with you. Problem is Angular Material has flexbox issues in crossbrowsers. Materializing with Bootstrap may be a better alternative